# Generated a Nested Object from TLV

Tags: javascript

I am trying to parse a TLV string and need to generate a nested object from that string.

```js
const text = 'AA06ClaireCC04JackBB03TomEE05James'
```

The output needs to look like this:

```js
"Acrobatic Artist": {
    "AA": {
      "Claire": {
        "Curious Camper": {
          "CC": {
            "Jack": {
              "Baddest Banana": {
                "BB": {
                  "Tom": {
                    "Energetic Elephant": {
                      "EE": {
                        "James" : "LASTRECORD"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is what I currently have:

```js
const map = {
  AA: 'Acrobatic Artist',
  BB: 'Baddest Banana',
  CC: 'Curious Camper',
  DD: 'Desperate Driver',
  EE: 'Energetic Elephant'
}

function createJson(str) {
    let json = {}
    let remainingText = str

    while(remainingText.length > 0) {
       const tag = remainingText.substring(0, 2)
       const len = remainingText.substring(2, 4)
       const val = remainingText.substring(4, len)
       const offset = tag.length + len.length + parseInt(len, 16)

       remainingText = remainingText.substring(offset)
       console.log('new text: ' + remainingText)
    
       json[map[tag]] = {}
       json[map[tag]][tag] = {}
       json[map[tag]][tag][val] = {}    
  }
  return json
}
```

But this just creates an object that looks like this:

```js
{
  Acrobatic Artist: {
    AA: { 
      Claire: {} 
    }
  },
  Baddest Banana: {
    BB: { 
      Tom: {} 
    }
  },
  Curious Camper: {
    CC: { 
      Jack: {} 
    }
  },
  Energetic Elephant: {
    EE: { 
      James: {} 
    }  
  }
}
```

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/kzaiwo/y9m2h60t/8/

Note:
Please disregard the `LASTRECORD` part. I just added that to complete the key-value pair (for the last pair) in the above example. Thank you!

Thanks!

Comment: Where does `"LASTRECORD"` come from?

Comment: Please disregard the LASTRECORD part. I just added that to complete the key-value pair (for the last pair) in my example. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep a reference to a `prev` value, which starts off as the original `json` object, you can then continuously update it and its children. When you're updating your object within the `while` loop you can update `prev`, and set it to the last child object that you create so that on the next iteration of your loop that particular child object will be updated to contain the new key-value pairs.

```js
const map = {
  AA: 'Acrobatic Artist',
  BB: 'Baddest Banana',
  CC: 'Curious Camper',
  DD: 'Desperate Driver',
  EE: 'Energetic Elephant'
};

const text = 'AA06ClaireCC04JackBB03TomEE05James';

function createJson(str) {
  let json = {};
  let prev = json;
  let remainingText = str;

  while (remainingText.length > 0) {
    const tag = remainingText.substring(0, 2);
    const len = remainingText.substring(2, 4);
    const val = remainingText.substring(4, 4 + parseInt(len, 16));
    const offset = tag.length + len.length + parseInt(len, 16);

    remainingText = remainingText.substring(offset);

    prev[map[tag]] = {};
    prev[map[tag]][tag] = {};
    prev = prev[map[tag]][tag][val] = {};
  }
  return json;
}

console.log(createJson(text));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a simple and easily understandable solution!

Answer (score 1):

Given the regular structure of your string (2-character code + 2-character number + characters), you can use a simple regex to split out the various parts.

From there you can (flat) map each section into an array of keys.

Finally, you can [*reduce-right*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) the array to produce the result you want.

```js
const map = {AA:"Acrobatic Artist",BB:"Baddest Banana",CC:"Curious Camper",DD:"Desperate Driver",EE:"Energetic Elephant"};
const text = "AA06ClaireCC04JackBB03TomEE05James";

// Parses a code, length and value from the start of the provided string
const parseSection = (str) => {
  const [, code, valueLength] = str.match(/^(\w{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/);
  const length = parseInt(valueLength, 16) + 4;
  return {
    code,
    length,
    type: map[code],
    value: str.slice(4, length),
  };
};

// Iterates through the string, extracting sections until finished
const parseTlv = (str) => {
  const sections = [];
  while (str.length) {
    const section = parseSection(str);
    sections.push(section);
    str = str.slice(section.length);
  }
  return sections;
};

// Map each section to a flat array of keys then reduce-right to form
// a tree structure
const lastRecord = {};
const result = parseTlv(text)
  .flatMap(({ type, code, value }) => [type, code, value])
  .reduceRight(
    (obj, key) => ({
      [key]: obj,
    }),
    lastRecord
  );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two part solution:

1. `for()` loop: create an array of items based on `<tag><len><val>` patterns
2. `.reduce()`: build the nested object from the items array

```js
const input = 'AA06ClaireCC04JackBB03TomEE05James';
const tagMap = {
  AA: 'Acrobatic Artist',
  BB: 'Baddest Banana',
  CC: 'Curious Camper',
  DD: 'Desperate Driver',
  EE: 'Energetic Elephant'
};

let items = [];
for(let i = 0; i < input.length; ) {
  let tag = input.substring(i, i + 2);
  let len = parseInt(input.substring(i + 2, i + 4), 16);
  let val = input.substring(i + 4, i + 4 + len);
  items.push([tag, val]);
  i += 4 + len;
}
let result = {};
items.reduce((obj, arr) => {
  const tag = arr[0];
  const val = arr[1];
  const name = tagMap[tag] || 'unknown';
  //console.log(name, tag, val);
  [name, tag, val].forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = {};
    obj = obj[key];
  });
  return obj;
}, result);
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
{
  "Acrobatic Artist": {
    "AA": {
      "Claire": {
        "Curious Camper": {
          "CC": {
            "Jack": {
              "Baddest Banana": {
                "BB": {
                  "Tom": {
                    "Energetic Elephant": {
                      "EE": {
                        "James": {}
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: the resulting object has an empty `{}` as the innermost value; you could replace that with `"LASTRECORD"` if needed

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93length%E2%80%93value. The numbers indicate the value length. The issue with ignoring the numbers is that you can accidentally interpret a value as a code+length if it matches the expression

Comment: I changed the code to take the value length into account